# java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods (Junit)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I am using Junit 4.11 and intellij. I have two test classes that I want to run them through suite, however I get the `no runnable methods` exception.

Here are the test classes:

```
public class TrackingServiceTest {

    private TrackingService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        service = new TrackingService();
    }

    @Test
    public void NewTrackingServiceTotalIsZero() {
        assertEquals("tracking service total was not zero", 0, service.getTotal());
    }

    @Test
    public void WhenAddingProteinTotalIncreasesByThatAmount(){
        service.addProtein(10);
        assertEquals("protein amount was not correct", 10, service.getTotal());
    }

    @Test
    public void WhenRemovingProteinTotalRemainsZero(){
        service.removeProtein(5);
        assertEquals("Total suppose to be zero after removing protein",0, service.getTotal());
    }
    @Test (expected = InvalidGoalException.class)
    public void WhenGoalIsSetToLessThanZeroExceptionIsThrown() throws InvalidGoalException {
        service.setGoal(-5);
    }

    @Test (timeout = 100)
    @Ignore
    public void BadTest(){
        for(int i=0; i<100000000; i++)
            service.addProtein(i);
    }
}
```

And here is another sample test class just to check suite:

```
public class HelloJUnitTest {

    private TrackingService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        service = new TrackingService();
    }

    @Test
    public void NewTrackingServiceTotalIsZero() {
        assertEquals("tracking service total was not zero", 0, service.getTotal());
    }
}
```

And this is my suite class:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(value = {
        TrackingService.class,
        HelloJUnitTest.class
})
public class ProteinTrackerSuite {

}
```

[image]

Comment: works for me, can you post your `Run configuration` from IntelliJ?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski how can I share my run configuration?

Comment: Click `Run` -> `Edit configurations`, select your test configuration and paste here some details from it

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski okay added screenshot

Comment: I have made exactly the same project and configuration - it works well for me. Have you tried invalidating your cache? `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart`  -> `Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski yes just did it, still getting same exception

Comment: is the code you posted exactly the same as the code you have in project? are all these classes in separate files?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski yes they are in separate files

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski found the issue, at SuiteClasses `TrackingService.class` suppose to be `TrackingServiceTest.class`, that was silly mistake that took my time and yours.